# Why i always get this error "gyp ERR! stack" NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Always when i install new npm package i get this error:

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/baruchmashasha/Desktop/Deloitte-DS-Server/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/baruchmashasha/Desktop/Deloitte-DS-Server/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v13.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I read some post here and try to fix it but its still show up.
The server work good but this error is bothering me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please read this : https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-macos

Extract:

> On macOS
>
> Python v2.7, v3.5, v3.6, or v3.7
>
> Xcode
>
> You also need to install the XCode Command Line Tools by running
>   `xcode-select --install`. Alternatively, if you already have the full
>   Xcode installed, you can find them under the menu Xcode -> Open
>   Developer Tool -> More Developer Tools.... This step will install
>   clang, clang++, and make.
>
> If your Mac has been upgraded to macOS Catalina (10.15), please read
>   macOS_Catalina.md.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're looking for is the first line.

> gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!

You don't have Xcode or its Command Line Tools installed, which is why `gyp`, the bit Node.js generally uses to build native code, fails.

You're apparently trying to install `fsevents`, which is an optional dependency to watch for file system events, used by many dev servers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i install Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1 from apple site and now everything work.
Link:

[Apple Developers Software Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)